# XPATH to select "td" elements between "h2" tag and <h2> tag or between "h2" tag and </table> tag, whichever is immediate

Tags: html, xpath

I am trying to find XPATH to fetch "*td*" elements between "*h2*" tag and "*h2*" tag or between "*h2*" tag and closing "*table*" tag, which ever is immediate.

**HTML Code**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="dc-section" >
             <h2>HEADING-1</h2>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="dc-table-name" >Country</td>
          <td class="dc-table-value" >India</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="dc-table-name" >Country</td>
          <td class="dc-table-value" >Nepal</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="dc-section" >
            <h2>HEADING-2</h2>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="dc-table-name" >Country</td>
          <td class="dc-table-value" >USA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="dc-table-name" >Country</td>
          <td class="dc-table-value" >Canada</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Given HEADING-1, need td elements with value "*Country*"->"*India*" and "*Country*"->"*Nepal*". Given HEADING-2, need td elements with value "*Country*"->"*USA*" and "*Country*"->"*Canada*".

Tried using below XPATH, but for the given HEADING-1, it selects all "td" values.

How to frame a common XPATH expression that works to fetch "td" elements for both "*HEADING-1*" and "*HEADING-2*"?

**XPATH** (Not working)

```
//h2[text()='HEADING-1']/following::td
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe instead of trying to match the following `td`, you check the first preceding `tr` with an `h2` to see if it matches...

```xml
//tr[not(td/h2)][preceding-sibling::tr[td/h2][1][starts-with(td/h2,'HEADING-1')]]/td
```

Comment: Very clever! And straight XPath 1.0, too.

Answer (score 1):

**NB**: This is a reply to the original (unedited) question.

Using `xmlstarlet`
here but it should be comprehensible (XPath 1.0):

(**Edited** 2023-04-26: missed the first part of the question)

> Given HEADING-1, need td elements with value "Country":

```sh
# shellcheck shell=sh
xmlstarlet select -R -I -t \
  -c '//tr[td/h2/text()="HEADING-1"]/following-sibling::tr[1]/td' \
 file.xml
```

Output:

```xml
<xsl-select>
  <td class="dc-table-name">Country</td>
  <td class="dc-table-value">India</td>
</xsl-select>
```

> How to frame a common XPATH expression that works to fetch "td"
> elements for both "HEADING-1" and "HEADING-2"?

```sh
# shellcheck shell=sh
xmlstarlet select -R -I -t -c '//tr/td[not(h2)]' file.xml
```

which selects `td` elements with a `tr` parent and no `h2` children.

Output:

```xml
<xsl-select>
  <td class="dc-table-name">Country</td>
  <td class="dc-table-value">India</td>
  <td class="dc-table-name">Country</td>
  <td class="dc-table-value">USA</td>
</xsl-select>
```

---

As an alternative, if you want to process the blocks separately, you
could use the `EXSLT`
[`set:leading`](https://exslt.github.io/set/functions/leading/index.html)
function:

```sh
# shellcheck shell=sh
xmlstarlet select \
  -R -I -t \
  -m '//tr/td[@class="dc-section"]' \
    -e 'div' \
      -c 'set:leading(following::td,following::td[@class="dc-section"][1])' \
file.xml
```

Output:

```xml
<xsl-select>
  <div>
    <td class="dc-table-name">Country</td>
    <td class="dc-table-value">India</td>
  </div>
  <div>
    <td class="dc-table-name">Country</td>
    <td class="dc-table-value">USA</td>
  </div>
</xsl-select>
```

Add a `-C` option before `-t` in the last command to get a copy of
the stylesheet:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="exslt set">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl-select>
      <xsl:for-each select="//tr/td[@class=&quot;dc-section&quot;]">
        <xsl:element name="div">
          <xsl:copy-of select="set:leading(following::td,following::td[@class=&quot;dc-section&quot;][1])"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl-select>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. I am using Selenium (Java) and looking for an xpath expression to select only td elements within a header. Please advise. Thank you!

Comment: @VasanthSubramanian: I updated my answer. If this is not what you had in mind then I suggest you edit your posting to include the expected output.

Comment: Thanks @urznow, your updated solution works partially now. If there are more than one <tr> tag, it selects the first one currently. The number of <tr> tag can be dynamic. I am updating the question. Could you please advise?

Comment: @VasanthSubramanian: Your edited question is a rather different one. I don't think you can do the required grouping in a single XPath 1.0 expression, i.e. select all `following-sibling::tr` and then limit that selection to those which have `tr/td/h2/text() = "HEADING-1"` as first `preceding-sibling`.